# AD authentication not updating

Tags: authentication

I have a problem with AD authentication. When I add a user to an AD group the user gets instant access. However if I remove a user that user continues to have access till the following morning. I found the only way to immediately cut access is to do an iisreset but obviously this isn't a practical solution. Just wondering if this behaviour is normal. Incidentally I have tried reducing the token timeout.  It makes no difference nor does getting the user to logout and log back in. I don't seem to remember having this problem in 2007. It's only happening in SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do User Profile Synchronization and run [Set-SPProfileServiceApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff608004%28v=office.15%29.aspx) cmdlet with

```
-PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

to delete users that were deleted from AD.

Comment: That works for someone who leaves the organisation but in my case I am only removing access to a specific AD group. They still belong to other Groups.